# Simple set question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is

$(R \cup P \cup \neg Q) \cap (R \cup P)$ equivalent to just $R \cup P$,

why can we ignore the $\neg Q$?

Would it just because the truth tables would be equivalent?

Comment: @testpilot Apparently the complement of set $\;Q\;$ in the universal set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the intersection:

$$x\in(R\cup P\cup\neg Q)\cap (R\cup P)\implies\begin{cases}x\in R\cup P\cup\neg Q\\\underline{\text{and}}\\x\in R\cup P \end{cases}\;\implies\;x\in R\cup P$$

The other inclusion is almost immediate. Try it.